# Call() that will call function with function name(in string) and params (any type)

Tags: rust

Here are the example,this was my first thought and i stucked here. How can I do with it or is there other approach to do this.

Objective: Call() that will call function with function name(in string) and params (any type)

```
fn diplay(input: i32){
  println!("{}", input);
}

fn diplay_float(input: f32){
  println!("{}", input);
}

call(name: &str, params: x){
  match name{
    "display" => display(params),
    "display_float" => display(params),
    _ => println!("Invalid input")
  }
}
```

---

Update of question: There maybe many functions and I wanted to use the `run("func name", param);` to call out the function. Is there any approach to do this?

```
struct First;
struct Second;

Impl First{
  fn some_function(param: i32){
    ...
  };
}


Impl Second{
  fn some_other_function(param: i32, param2: i32){
    ...
  };
}

trait MyTrait{
  fn run(name: str, params: ?);
}

fn main(){
  run("some_function", 23);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Rust is statically typed language, it is expected to know all functions and types at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

The Rust way of doing this is to define your function in a trait, then implement that trait for the types you want to support:

```
trait MyDisplay {
    fn display (&self);
}

impl MyDisplay for i32 {
    fn display (&self) {
        println!("{}", self);
    }
}

impl MyDisplay for f32 {
    fn display (&self) {
        println!("{}", self);
    }
}

fn call<T: MyDisplay> (input: T) {
    input.display();
}

fn main() {
    let i = 42i32;
    let f = std::f32::consts::PI;
    call (i);
    call (f);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=34eb722001c0f8c25852eac30a281220)

Comment: Thank for the answer, it helped me and gave me some idea on rust.